# How can I use branch code based on TypeScript types in Svelte?

Tags: typescript, svelte

> Similar to [Typescript: How to branch based on type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54543838/typescript-how-to-branch-based-on-type) but this is using Svelte, I am already using run-time type guards per that answer, and Svelte is still throwing errors.

I have an array named `collectablesInFolders`, of type `Collectable | Folder`.

`Folders` have a `folderName` property. Collectables don't have a `folderName`. I have a runtime type check for this:

```
const isAFolder = (collectableOrFolder: Collectable | Folder) => {
  return Object.hasOwn(collectableOrFolder, "folderName");
};
```

I am using the type check to branch my logic in Svelte:

```html
{#each collectablesInFolders as collectableOrFolder}
  {#if isAFolder(collectableOrFolder)}
    <div class="collectable">
      <img src={FolderSVG} alt={collectableOrFolder.folderName} crossOrigin="anonymous" class="shadow" />
    </div>
  {:else}
    <CollectableThumb {collectableOrFolder} />
  {/if}
{/each}
```

Svelte/TypeScript gives an error that `folderName` doesn't exist on `Collectable` items:

> Property folderName does not exist on type.

That's true, but that code is in a branch that's only for items with a `folderName` key.

Likewise Svelte/TypeScript also gives an error that:

> Type '{ collectableOrFolder: Collectable | Folder; }' is not assignable to type '{ collectable: Collectable; }'.

That's true as well, but that code is in a branch that's only for items that don't have a `folderName` key - ie Collectables.

I've tried using `as` but doing `{collectableOrFolder.folderName as Folder}` doesn't seem to be allowed in Svelte HTML.

**How can I use branch code based on TypeScript types in Svelte?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what you would do in TypeScript:

```js
function isAFolder(collectableOrFolder: Collectable | Folder): collectableOrFolder is Folder {
  return Object.hasOwn(collectableOrFolder, "folderName");
}
```

Then in Svelte:

```html
{#if isAFolder(collectableOrFolder)}
  <div class="collectable">
    <img src={FolderSVG} alt={collectableOrFolder.folderName} crossOrigin="anonymous" class="shadow" />
  </div>
{:else}
  <CollectableThumb collectable={collectableOrFolder} />
{/if}
```

Comment: I've added the Svelte-y bits to the answer above, hope that's OK & thanks again!